# Difference between Spark application vs job vs stage vs task?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

As per my understanding:

```
1. Spark application is a whole piece of code (jar) 
2. Spark job is subset of code - for each action one job will be created
3. Spark stage is subset of job - whenever data shuffle happens (wide transformation) - one stage will be created 
4. Spark task is the actual task which runs our code - for each partition - one task will be created
```

Now, i have one rdd with numbers. I want to filter even and odd numbers from the given rdd and save as even and odd text file respectively .

As per the above description , there should be 2 jobs created . But there is only one job created.

Can anyone please clarify the logic how spark job/stage/task are being created.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263270/what-is-the-concept-of-application-job-stage-and-task-in-spark

Comment: "I want to filter even and odd numbers from the given rdd and save as even and odd text file respectively ."

Can you show a code?

Comment: Hi @SergeHarnyk,

    `rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
    even = rdd.filter(lambda x:x%2 == 0).saveAsTextFile("even")
   odd = rdd.filter(lambda x:x%2 == 1).saveAsTextFile("odd")`

Comment: @Newbie_Bigdata are you sure that two jobs were created? How do you define it?

Comment: @SergeHarnyk , It didn't create 2 jobs. That's what my question. When we run 2 different actions like (1. saveAsTextFile, 2. Show), it creates 2 jobs. 
or when we read from 2 files/rdd/df and run 2 same action(saveAsTextFile) also creates 2 jobs.

But when i read from same rdd and perform same action 2 times, it creates 1 job.

Could you please help me to understand the logic behind the jobs creation in spark application.

Comment: @Newbie_Bigdata sorry, my question is opposite. Are you sure that it creates one job? Just checked a code similar to your, with saving of two files - and what I see in logs:
```INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: parquet at EntryPoint.java:47
INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: parquet at EntryPoint.java:53```