# What is 'showString' in Spark UI? Are the code blocks below different?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

```
(1)df.createOrReplaceTempView("dftable")
sqldf = spark.sql('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dftable')
sqldf.show()
```

```
(2)df.createOrReplaceTempView("dftable")
sqldf = spark.sql('SELECT * FROM dftable')
sqldf.count()
```

What is the difference between above two codes? (1) takes 20 seconds to perform while (2) only takes 5 seconds. Only difference that I was able to notice is that in their corresponding stages, there is something like "showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0" in (1) while (2) has "count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0". I attached their corresponding stages too. Stage 46 is for (1) and Stage 43 is for (2).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcf9A.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGOxC.png

Comment: How many rows does query 2 return? What does query 1 say it should be?

Comment: @jarlh query for 2: https://imgur.com/vbfk1wZ query for 1: https://imgur.com/wq7Lt9R

Comment: Please, no images or links to images. Show us data as formatted text instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already mentioned in you question, the 1st query is using `.show()` while the 2nd query is using the `.count()`, which is completely two different action. Therefore, you can see that they have different spark job (blue boxes) when you check their execution DAG. Because they are using different action, some action are expensive than other action, especially when you use the action that bring the data back to the driver node (e.g. `.collect()`) so you can't expect they use the same time.

Back to your example, the reason why `.count()` is faster than `.show()` is because `.count()` is distributed and the final count (number) will be the sum of all partition which is done by driver, while `.show()` need to fetches the amount of data that you requested (default `20`) back to the driver.

You can try different expensive action like `.collect()` to see how different action require time and resource.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am currently trying Spark SQL and trying to understand how it works. in the first code block, I was trying to find the count with the ''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dftable" query, but queries return tables. So I used .show() to see the count. My question is: Does spark parallelize queries too? How can I see that the query of the first code block executed parallel to the each partition of the data.

Comment: @TacettinEmreBök I won't say the queries are "parallelize", because it's a SQL-like statement and it will only stay in the driver node, but the job and task behind the SQL logic does. That's why spark can do distributed computing. I assume you have the concept of `application`, `job`, `stage` and `task` in Spark, if not, you can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263270/what-is-the-concept-of-application-job-stage-and-task-in-spark. If you want to see how your tasks are executed in parallel, you can check your spark log/go to the Web UI and click the stage to see.